# ExtJs 3.4 : Margin doesn't apply for the small arrow of the combo box

Tags: extjs, combobox, margin

I have av ExtJs combo box as following.

```
new Ext.form.ComboBox({
                store : routeStore,
                displayField : 'rName',
                valueField : 'rCode',
                fieldLabel : 'Select Fixed Route',
                id : 'routeCombo',
                typeAhead : true,
                forceSelection : true,
                mode : 'local',
                triggerAction : 'all',
                selectOnFocus : true,
                editable : false,
                hidden : false,
                disabled : true,
                minChars : 1,
                hideLabel : true,
                width : 210,
                emptyText : 'Select Fixed Route',
                style: {
                    marginTop: '10px'
                }
            });
```

I am using ExtJs 3.4. I've tried to set margin top for my combo box.

```
style: {
 marginTop: '10px'
}
```

Then my combo box looks like following.

[image]

It doesn't apply for small arrow of the combo box.

How should I apply margin for a combo with it's small drop down arrow ?

Please help me

Answer (score 1):

Edit Following thing in your css.

The problem here is , it is a box component on which margintop is set and arrow is an image rendered.

*1. In css,*

> ```
> .arrowClass {
>       margin-top: 10px;
> }
> ```

But, Combo box have an element triggerClass which can be used to set style for arrow too.

*2.In js, Include this in your config of ComboBox.*

```
triggerClass:'arrowClass',
style:{
      marginTop: '10px'
}
```